# D3 multiline chart with nested data

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I have nested data like this & want to draw a multi-line chart with specific channel & category selection legends. How do I approach with d3 for this kind of data

```
var data=[{channelName='A'
       values=[
               { category="min"
                 values=[{value=1,time="2015-05-05"},{value=3,time="2015-05-                    05"},{value=2,time="2015-05-05"}]
               },
               { category="max"
                 values=[{value=1,time="2015-05-05"},{value=3,time="2015-05-   05"},{value=2,time="2015-05-05"}]
               }
              ]
      }
      {channelName='B'
       values=[
               { category="min"
                 values=[{value=1,time="2015-05-05"},{value=3,time="2015-05-                    05"},{value=2,time="2015-05-05"}]
               },
               { category="max"
                 values=[{value=1,time="2015-05-05"},{value=3,time="2015-05-05"},{value=2,time="2015-05-05"}]
               }
              ]
      }
     ]
```

Comment: Want to draw a chart with y axis as values & x axis as time